# Java: How to make lint respect the RuntimeException thrown from a inner function call?

Tags: java, android-studio, lint

I'm writing Android code using Android Studio, and it performs automatic lint checking when writing code.

I have a code snippet like this:

```
Obj fun() {
    Obj o;
    if (SOME_CONDITION) {
        if (SOME_OTHER_CONDITION) {
            o = SOMETHING;
        } else {
            panic();
        }
    } else {
        panic();
    }
    return o;
}
```

where `panic()` is another function like this

```
void panic() {
    throw new IllegalStateException();
}
```

However, the lint checker reports error that o may not have been initialized.
Apparently when going to the `else` branch, an `IllegalStateException` (a subclass of `RuntimeException`) is thrown, so the execution has terminated.

Note the `o = SOMETHING;` statement is a simplified description. The actual code is more complicated, and contains other condition checks.

Adding `throws RuntimeException` (or `IllegalStateException`) to `panic()` doesn't make any difference.

How can I tell the linter that it won't go wrong (without catching the exception and throw it again)?

Comment: If you are really sure that moving to the `else` block will always result in an `IllegalStateException`, then check for that condition first and throw the exception. Something along the line of [this](https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html). If you can't, then the other alternative is to initialize `o` with `null`.

Comment: You should not do that. If the only point of a method call is to throw an exception unconditionally, make it return an exception instance instead and throw it in your function which actually should be throwing it. Somebody may change the non-contractual semantics of panic later to throw conditionally and your method that uses panic will get a hidden bug.

Comment: @MDSayemAhmed Maybe I over-simplified my case. The updated code snippet may clarify it better. The key point is that there may be multiple places where `panic` is expected to be called, so I don't think it's a good idea to place the check everywhere. The GuardClauses may be a good choice for simple cases (e.g. there is only ONE variable to be assigned), but may not be good enough for complicated ones.

Comment: @OlegSklyar The `panic` method is a helper function written by myself, only to wrap some common things I'd like to do when debugging (e.g. logging, and then throw exception). It's not simply "only" throwing an exception, but yes it'd unconditionally. The whole point is how to make it easier for simple cases / quick prototyping while keeping some possibility to debug. I think "you are not expected to do this" doesn't mean "you can't do this", unless this is enforced by the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A local variable must be definitely assigned

What you want is not possible. It's not merely a linter rule in Android studio, it's a language rule enforced by the compiler. [JLS 16 states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html) (emphasis added):

> For every access of a local variable or blank `final` field `x`, `x` must be definitely assigned before the access, or a *compile-time error occurs.*

## What you *can* do

Redefine `panic()`:

```
RuntimeException panic() {
  return new IllegalStateException();
}
```

Then use it like this to allow the compiler to verify that the flow of control never results in access to an un-assigned variable:

```
...
} else {
    throw panic();
}
...
```

The `panic()` method could perform additional work, although logging *and then* throwing an exception is discouraged as it tends to cause redundant logging.

Comment: This will work, but panic should be renamed something like CreateException. In this case having it do additional work would also break SRP.

Comment: Logging and throwing makes sense in Android environment, where I can't collect the exception message (and stack trace). I agree with @GonenI that the method then needs to be renamed (and this is still a little more complicated because I still need to write `throw` after calling `pacnic`, though a LOT better than previously).

Comment: @renyuneyun Why can't you collect the message and stack trace?

Comment: Well, how can I (if the phone is not mine, i.e. not connecting via adb to my computer)? Some users just don't know how to use adb.

Comment: @renyuneyun Normally you'd log exceptions only when they are handled and not propagated to a caller. If this is a thread that you didn't create, like a UI thread, you can still [install an uncaught exception handler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler-java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler-) on that thread to do the logging. When setting yours, you should check to see if there is one already, and delegate to it after invoking your own hooks.

Comment: Though, I'm still expecting an "answer" about 1) if what I want is possible 2) how to achieve that (assumming possible)? I prefer to wait a while before accecpting the best known answer (yes, this answer) about "how to minimizing the cost [of restructuring and writing things] while agreeing with lint (without knowing whether we can change it's behavior or not)".

Comment: @renyuneyun I updated my answer to address your question more directly.

Comment: @erickson Thanks for the update :) So you mean an exception thrown by a function call should be "definitely assigned" (to a variable)? But why could the explicit `throws Exception` snooze the alarm (of linter)?

Comment: @renyuneyun No, I meant that, in your example, there are paths to `return o` that don't definitely assign the variable `o`. If this code compiled, it would permit the return of an undefined value under certain conditions. When you abort these paths by throwing an exception, the compiler can see that the remaining paths definitely assign `o` before it is returned. That satisfies the compiler.

Comment: @erickson I see. It makes a lot of sense now: calling a function which "may" throw an exception doesn't guarentee the execution will be terminated at that point (i.e. this exception will always be thrown). And it also means: there is no way to annotate / mark something which will "definitely" throw an exception (except for explicitly throwing it).

Answer (score 1):

Lint is correct. Consider that "panic" could be changed in the future, or overridden by subclasses not to throw an exception. o will be uninitialized. If you really want lint to shut up about it, just initialize it.

A better option would be to move the declaration of o and the return statement to the branch where o=something. That's the only place it is really used, and it is obscuring the true intent of the code in other places. Instead of the return at the end of the function , throw an exception. If panic() really throws an exception, that line will never be called, but it should keep everyone happy.

In fact, depending on your real code, you may be able to simplify further:

```
Obj fun() {
    if (SOME_CONDITION && SOME_OTHER_CONDITION) {
            return SOMETHING;
    } 
    panic();
    throw new RuntimeException("We don't expect to get here");
}
```

Comment: Again, stated in the revised question statement, this is only a simplified code, only to present the problem more directly. The actual code does a lot more condition checks and extra stuffs (and I thought they are way too complicated so I didn't copy it directly), so simplifying them like this is not acceptable (lots of returns, because there are lots of assignments under different conditions).

Comment: One shorter comment: adding `throws RuntimeException` to the definition of `panic()` doesn't stop lint from criticising this.

Comment: That makes sense because all java functions implicitly throw RuntimeException. That is basically the definition of RuntimeException: Any function can throw it at any time, without needing to declare it in a throws clause. Adding throws RuntimeException has no effect in Java.